# Show source code with synatx highlight in Django html page

Tags: django

I searched around and doesn't seem to have any good solutions.

The closest one: [django-pygments](https://github.com/sniku/django-pygments/blob/master/README) doesn't support template context/variable passing as language option.

I want to know if anyone one know of a good solution that supports snippet type passed as template context?

Thanks.

Comment: How about a JavaScript solution, like [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. I am going to take a look at this. I tried highlight.js and I don't know why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template:

```
{% content|pygmentize:lang %}
```

View:

```
def show(request):
    ctx = dict()
    ctx['content'] = 'alert("hello");'
    ctx['lang'] = 'javascript'
    return render(request,'template.html',ctx)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Is this the solution to django-pygments? Or doesit only require me to use python's pygement.

Comment: This is with django-pygments.